# OkHttp-Sent-Millis and OkHttp-Received-Millis does not get printed on log: I want to collect Metrics

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to calculate how much time it took for a REST API webservice call. I came to know OkHttp/Retrofit prints log statements with `OkHttp-Received-Millis` and `OkHttp-Sent-Millis` in log. 
But I do not see any of these statements printing.
What I see all this:

**What I see in Android Studio LogCat**

```
2019-08-04 10:04:36.765 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
2019-08-04 10:04:36.765 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 189
2019-08-04 10:04:36.765 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: x-api-key: 6a6bacf-5b2-11e-911-005056b6
2019-08-04 10:04:36.770 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: {"email_id":"checkthis@cool.com","first_name":"Amber","gender":"FEMALE","last_name":"Heard","password":"Password1!","phone_number":"123456","reset_enabled":false,"username":"iamchandra7"}
2019-08-04 10:04:36.770 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: --> END POST (189-byte body)
2019-08-04 10:04:38.386 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request https://mywebserice.herokuapp.com/middleservice/api/v1/users/ (1611ms)
2019-08-04 10:04:38.387 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Date: Sun, 04 Aug 2019 17:04:38 GMT
2019-08-04 10:04:38.388 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Server: Apache
2019-08-04 10:04:38.389 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2019-08-04 10:04:38.390 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2019-08-04 10:04:38.390 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2019-08-04 10:04:38.392 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
2019-08-04 10:04:38.392 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 258
2019-08-04 10:04:38.395 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
2019-08-04 10:04:38.396 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: Connection: close
2019-08-04 10:04:38.418 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: {"status":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Invalid Request","errors":["Password does not meet the requirements. It should not contain username, first name or last name. It should not contain any dictionary words. It should not be one of the last 12 passwords used"]}
2019-08-04 10:04:38.419 6651-7080/com.my.project D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (258-byte body)
```

**What Extra Information I want to See**

> As shown below That `OkHttp-Sent-Millis` and `OkHttp-Received-Millis` is information what
>   I want to see and I want to be able to read it in code and update that
>   to another Metrics API endpoint.

(Copied from another post)

```
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1463388540799
05-16 16:49:01.225 19039-19069/com.zdd.movie D/zddHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1463388541225
```

**My Code:**

**Gradle File:**

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

**My Retrofit instantiation**

```
   @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("myProjectRetrofit")
    Retrofit providesMyProjectRetrofit(@Named("myProjeect-server-url") String baseUrl){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(getHttpClient().build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    private OkHttpClient.Builder getHttpClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        okHttpClient.connectTimeout(Constants.connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        okHttpClient.readTimeout(Constants.readTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.writeTimeout(Constants.writeTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return okHttpClient;
    }
```

Comment: "I came to know OkHttp/Retrofit prints log statements with OkHttp-Received-Millis and OkHttp-Sent-Millis in log" -- not in the current version of `HttpLoggingInterceptor`. See [the `4.0.1` version](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-4.0.1/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt), for example. The amount of time that the request took is shown as part of the response (see the `(1611ms)` value in your output).

Comment: @CommonsWare: Can you please tell me if there is a better way to read that value?

Comment: If you want to get that value in code, create a custom interceptor and calculate it yourself from timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to create a custom interceptor. An interceptor will allow you to log more info in regards to your network requests. Good Luck!

https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

```
class MyInterceptor: Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain: Response {
          // Do your work here!!
     }
}
```

Comment: I followed the same. But it does not print the values that I am looking for. `OkHttp-Received-Millis` and `OkHttp-Sent-Millis`. As @CommonsWare mentioned it does not print anymore in the current versions. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @Chandra: A custom interceptor -- meaning an `Interceptor` implementation that you write yourself -- will only print to Logcat what you program it to print. So, if it is not logging those lines, that is because you did not write the code to log those lines. Your question shows that you used an *existing* interceptor (`HttpLoggingInterceptor`) and did not write a custom one.

Comment: Clarified my answer for some more insight.